# Mutable modifications of a Vector using ST

Tags: haskell

I have been going through a School of Haskell tutorial on "modify and the ST monad". The question asks to come up with the code for modify which has the following type signature: `modify :: Unbox a => (forall s. MVector s a -> ST s ()) -> Vector a -> Vector a`
This is what the function does:

1. Creates a new mutable buffer the same length as the original vector
2. Copies the values from the original vector into the new mutable vector
3. Runs the provided ST action on the provided mutable vector
4. Unsafely freezes the mutable vector and returns it.

Also use runST from Control.Monad.ST

I have been playing around with it however I can't get from `ST s ()` to `Vector a`.

This is what I have:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Chp28v8 where

import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.STRef
import  qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V

modify' :: V.Unbox a => (forall s. MVector s a -> ST s ()) ->
                               V.Vector a -> V.Vector a
modify' fn v = runST $ do
  vm <- V.unsafeThaw v >>= newSTRef
  modifySTRef vm fn
  vm >>= V.unsafeFreeze
```

Comment: Please give us a starting point.  Include what code you've tried, and where it went wrong.

Comment: FWIW, I disagree with the close vote.  This is a perfectly reasonable question for SO, if it included more information about what was tried and didn't work.

Comment: Do you see how do this simpler exercise: write a `modify` that just uses `unsafeThaw` and then the function, and then `unsafeFreeze`? This will involve a little do-block with a line in the middle that has type `ST s ()` but the last line will have the type `ST s (Vector a)` In the middle you will apply the given modifying function that has type `(forall s. MVector s a -> ST s ())` but the result of applying it will have type `ST s ()`

Comment: `unsafeThaw` does not copy the original vector. You probably want to use `thaw` instead.

Comment: Changing from unsafeThaw to thaw doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Chp28v8 where

import Control.Monad.ST
import  qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable

modify' :: V.Unbox a => (forall s. MVector s a -> ST s ()) ->
                               V.Vector a -> V.Vector a
modify' fn v = runST $ do
  vm <- V.thaw v
  fn vm
  V.unsafeFreeze vm
```